# SQL How to assign correct dates to multiple nulls in sequential date columns

Tags: sql, date, null, date-range, sequential

I have a range of sequential dates for an employee and there are nulls in between.
The logic to handle nulls is as mentioned below:

if todate is null and next record fromdate has a value then todate is (next record fromdate-1)
if todate is null and there is no next record fromdate then default todate to 01/08/2020

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTS2O.png)

[Required Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XspRr.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: add sample data as text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started but as you don't state which dbms you are using the syntax for deducting one day is subject to lots of variation.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    FROMDATE DATE  NOT NULL
>   ,TODATE   DATE 
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('15/02/2016','30/04/2016');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/05/2016',NULL);
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('2/06/2016','16/10/2016');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('17/10/2016','31/12/2016');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/01/2017','14/02/2017');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('15/02/2017','31/12/2017');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/01/2018','14/02/2018');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('15/02/2018','20/02/2018');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('21/02/2018','31/03/2018');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/04/2018','31/12/2018');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/01/2019','31/03/2019');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/04/2019','31/12/2019');
> INSERT INTO mytable(FROMDATE,TODATE) VALUES ('1/01/2020',NULL);
>
> select
>     fromdate
>   , todate                                                        as todate_raw
>   , coalesce(todate,lag(fromdate,1) over(order by fromdate DESC)) as todate_new
> from mytable
> order by fromdate
> ```
>
> ```
> fromdate   | todate_raw | todate_new
> :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> 2016-02-15 | 2016-04-30 | 2016-04-30
> 2016-05-01 | null       | 2016-06-02
> 2016-06-02 | 2016-10-16 | 2016-10-16
> 2016-10-17 | 2016-12-31 | 2016-12-31
> 2017-01-01 | 2017-02-14 | 2017-02-14
> 2017-02-15 | 2017-12-31 | 2017-12-31
> 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-14
> 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-20 | 2018-02-20
> 2018-02-21 | 2018-03-31 | 2018-03-31
> 2018-04-01 | 2018-12-31 | 2018-12-31
> 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-31 | 2019-03-31
> 2019-04-01 | 2019-12-31 | 2019-12-31
> 2020-01-01 | null       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=06c8105c99b3429daed22eacb351fdb3)*

Comment: Thank you for this query. How do i do it for different workers. The example above works on one worker but when i apply it for all the workers, it doesn't give me the desired result. I have updated the data above.

Comment: Rhui images of data are useless, you really should provide sample data in a format that we can re-use (i.e. don't expect us to type out your data).  I suggest you look at how to use `PARTITION` inside the `OVER` clause something like this:  `coalesce(todate,lag(fromdate,1) over(partition by worker_id order by fromdate DESC))`

Comment: Thank you. I applied this logic and it worked. Also I tried adding the data as a table but as I am new to stack overflow, didn't know how to do it. Thanks anyway for your help. You are a life saver.